# How to create a react library for API calling?

Tags: reactjs

I have created a react library for UI components and now I want to create a react library for API calls, i have backend system which is used by multiple application and the APIS and data structures is same across multiple app, so I planning to move that reusable logic in a library. How can I do it? how can I make it configurable so that different applications can pass parameters?

Comment: The question is slightly misleading "React Library for API calling" does not make much sense as React is primarily concerned with user interfaces and not APIs. If I understand you correctly, what you want is a layer of abstraction over general purpose AJAX libraries like Axios. This is entirely possible but the question needs to be modified so that people can provide you meaningful answers.

Answer (score -1):

For library packaging and publishing, I suggest you take the help of [create-react-library](https://github.com/transitive-bullshit/create-react-library)

By default this library provides `microbundle-crl`, which is an abstracted version of `roll-up`. You can use either of them in this case.

Add all your required libraries in consumer application as peer dependencies, like below.

```
  "peerDependencies": {
    "react": "^17.0.1",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.1",
    "react-scripts": "4.0.1"
    "node-sass": "^4.14.0",
    "react-redux": "^7.2.2",
    "redux": "^4.0.5",
    "axios": "^0.21.1",
    "redux-saga": "^1.1.3",
  },
```

You might need to keep a global state using redux and if you wish to use sagas, axios, move those as peer dependencies like I've shown above.
While exporting, you might need to think about exporting your reducer, root-saga etc along with your whole package.

Comment: The question is more about abstracting out the logic dealing with API calls in the person's React UI Component library, not packaging the library itself.